# Cohen's d / Hedge's g: when to use 'paired' vs 'pooled' method

Tags: independence, effect-size, cohens-d

When calculating **Cohen's d** or **Hedge's g**, one can opt to use a *paired* or *pooled* method in handling variance.

I am working with a small sample size (up to 12 observations in each sample being compared), so I have opted to use **Hedge's g**. My data are from a repeated-measures design, so they are *not* independent. However, I have occasional missing observations from both datasets, so for example in some cases one of the test samples may have 11 observations, and the other may only have 9.

Given that my two samples are not independent, I assume that the correct thing to do would be to use the **paired** calculation method. However, given that I have occasional missing data, if I do this then I'd need to remove any pairs for which *either* sample has a missing observation. If I am making a comparison between two samples for which I have, say, 11 observations in one group and 9 in the other, it's possible that this pairwise deletion could lead to me only having 8 pairs left to compare.

In this case, is it better to use a **pooled** method (due to the rapidly diminishing sample size), or do I absolutely have to stick to using the **paired** method because my samples aren't independent?

In other words, can I avoid throwing away data in the calculation of *Hedge's g* by using the **pooled** method, even though my data are from a repeated-measures design?

Note: if it's relevant, I'm using the `effsize` package in R to handle my stats, and the `cohen.d()` function with the arguments `hedges.correction=TRUE` and `na.rm=TRUE`.

Comment: In paired comparisons _n_ is the number of complete pairs, without missings. Yo must remove all pairs with missing value. Or do imputation of missing values.

Comment: Your data are paired (not independent) and as such you cannot treat them as independent data. The formula for $d$ or $g$ for repeated measures data is similar but the computation of the standard error, and hence confidence interval, is different and depends on the correlation between the two time points as well as the sample size, etc. The classic reference by a student of Hedges is: Becker, B. J. (1988). Synthesizing standardized mean‐change measures. British Journal of Mathematical and Statistical Psychology, 41(2), 257-278.